# Shortcut for commenting in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Simple question: does anyone know of a shortcut key for commenting in Rmd?

In Knitr this can be done using CTRL + C, which produces in both writing and coding environment a comment line. This does not work in Rmd unfortunately.

At the moment I have to type out:

```
<!-- Comments -->
```

I am using R-studio.

Comment: presumably you're talking about RStudio?  I would say this sounds like a feature request for the RStudio folks ...

Comment: Yes I use R-studio. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a snippet under the "markdown" section:

[image]

(I made mine `hcm`) then type:

<kbd>hcm</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and it'll expand to whatever you want (mine was `<!-- -->`)

You can make the snippet text shorter as well.

I agree with Ben that you could go to RStudio support and ask for a kbd shortcut for this.

Comment: updated with image pic (which I shld have done earlier, apologies). and ignore the weird `-->`, I use the Fira Code font to get real arrows and other symbols.

Comment: Nice! You taught me to fish here... :)

Comment: Cool. I really like the SO kbd keys markup and _never_ get to use them. I _may_ have overindulged the use of them here tho :-)

Comment: Adding comment in .Rmd in RStudio is now supported by default using `Ctrl+Shift+C` or `Command+Shift+C`.  See `Help -> Keyboard Shortcuts Help`

Comment: @markdly this doesn't seem to work in .Rmd files anymore. However, is there a way to place the cursor inside the `<!-- -->` created by the snippet? So that I can just continue typing without interruption

Comment: @Haakonkas, the keyboard shortcuts only work for me on non-blank lines. Try typing a word and then use the shortcut. This should trigger the comment text and your cursor will still be inside so you can continue typing