# commenting out rmarkdown in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

Duplicate question because I can not comment ([Shortcut for commenting in Rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260971/shortcut-for-commenting-in-rmarkdown))

in Rstudio using shift-cmd(ctrl)-c or the 'comment/uncomment' line option produces a '#' that comments out the line in the editor, but upon compiling does not comment out the line.
using "  " comments out the line when compiled, but does not change the Rstudio font, making it difficult to use Rstudio for editing.
Am I missing something?

Comment: The shortcut is not support outside of code chunks I guess. Manually add HTML comments `<!-- ... -->` within RMarkdown content...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cmd-shift-c` (or `ctrl-shift-c` on Windows) to produce the comment symbol.  The comment tag added varies depending on which section of the document you are working in.

If you are working inside an RMarkdown chunk then `#` will appear.

To comment out text outside the code chunk with `<!-- -->` you first need to have some text entered on the line you wish to comment then, with the cursor located anywhere on the same line, try using the shortcut.

````
<!-- RMarkdown text wrapped in a comment --> 
```{r}
# Comment inside code chunk
```
````

Note commenting outside a code chunk using the shortcut *doesn't* work for me on a line containing only whitespace. I don't think this was the case in the previous version of RStudio (I'm using Version 1.1.383) but perhaps it's my memory that's faulty!

Comment: Ok It appears it was my mistake. In the text body it is possible to use the key shortcut. In a heading section, such as the abstract, acknowledgements etc. keyboard shortcuts result in #