# Custom comment method in R (other than #)

Tags: r, rstudio, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

## Question:

**Is there anyway to comment my code in a particular way**,e.g. `line commment`, `multilines comment`, `block comment`?

```
This is a single line comment, which has a keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Shift + C
# code 1

This is a multiline comment:
# code 1
# code 2
# code 3
# code 4

This is a block comment:(the number of '#' may be fixed or automatically computed)
##########################
#### my description 1 ####
#### my description 2 ####
#### my description 3 ####
##########################
```

There is a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260971/shortcut-for-commenting-in-rmarkdown) using code snippet to commment in markdown. I am wondering whether we can define our **own comment methods** in **Rstudio**?

Comment: roxygen2 package uses a special decorator, `#'`, which may be defined somewhere in the [source code](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/tree/master/R). So my guess is that it may be possible?